# How do I scrape <li> element that belongs to a particular class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape amazon(in) website. This is the [link](https://www.amazon.in/Philips-GC026-30-Fabric-Shaver/dp/B00TDD0YM4/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=GC026%2F30&qid=1554271608&s=gateway&sr=8-2) of product page that I am referring to.

I am trying to scrape the url of images which are present inside the ul > li and further down inside span tags, present on the top left side of the page.

The end result i need is a list of all the thumbnails of images, but not that of video

The following command works fine and gives me all the urls of all the thumbnails

```
response.xpath('*//div[@id="altImages"]/ul/li/span[@class="a-list-item"]/span/span/span/span/img/@src').extract()
```

The problem with above command is I am not able to differentiate whether the image belongs to that of a video thumbnail or of an image thumbnail.

To do so, I used the following command to get thumbnails that belong to an image:

```````````
response.xpath('*//div[@id="altImages"]/ul/li[contains(@class,"imageThumbnail")]/span[@class="a-list-item"]/span/span/span/span/img/@src').extract()

``````````
and

``````````
response.xpath('*//div[@id="altImages"]/ul/li[@class="a-spacing-small item imageThumbnail a-declarative"]/span[@class="a-list-item"]/span/span/span/span/img/@src').extract()
```````````

The class="a-spacing-small item imageThumbnail a-declarative" should give me only those elements that have the class 'imageThumbnail'.
but what i get is an empty list

What i am expecting in output is only urls of images that belong to class 'imageThumbnail', which in our example should be only 5 in numbers

Here is the link of the output that I am getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K8ZF.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use `CSS` selectors here, in special because you're handling classes. To pick all non-videos thumbnails you could use:

```py
response.css('#altImages li.item:not(.videoBlockIngress) img::attr(src)').getall()
```

Or, if with want to get only video thumbs:

```
response.css('#altImages .videoBlockIngress img::attr(src)').getall()
```

[More info on Parsel selectors](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: The above code worked fine. I tried the other way round to get only the url of video by not including the image class...The code goes like this: ````` response.css('#altImages li.item:not(.imageThumbnail) img::attr(src)').getall() ````` In this case I am still get the url of the image elements... What could be the reason.

Comment: Surely `.imageThumbnail` is a class added after the page loads, by some javascript code. Use the "view page source" shortcut in your browser to check if it is there. Anyways, I've updated the answer.